# firefox won't convert string to number in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, string, firefox, numbers

I making a web app in Flex using global coordinates

I get the coordinates as strings from a web service then I do something like this:

```
latStr:String = "28.7242100786401";
longStr:String = "-106.12635420984";

var cLat:Number = new Number(latStr);
var cLong:Number = new Number(longStr);
```

**This works PERFECT on IE and chrome, from the web server and when debugging locally, but *Firefox just works when debugging locally* and not from the web server, in the web server `cLat` and `cLong` return "`NaN`".**

check it out yourself, it should pop up an alert when you click on a result:
http://mundobuk.com/prueba/mapa/main.html?buscar=oxxo

so I tried using `parseFloat()`, but it rounds `cLat` to `28` and `cLong` to `-106` :(

Then I tried separating the decimals form integers, like from my example 28 and 7242100786401 then divide 7242100786401/10000000000000 = 0.7242100786401

having 2 numbers 28 and 0.7242100786401 I add them up

28 + 0.7242100786401 = 28.7242100786401

here is in code form:

```
var latArr:Array = latStr.split(".");
var longArr:Array = longStr.split(".");


var latDivStr:String = "1";
for (var i:int= 0; i< latArr[1].length; i++){
latDivStr += "0";
}

var longDivStr:String = "1";
for (var j:int = 0; j< longArr[1].length; j++){
longDivStr += "0";
}
var cLat:Number = parseFloat(latArr[0]) + arseFloat(latArr[1])/parseFloat(latDivStr);
var cLong:Number = parseFloat(longArr[0]) - parseFloat(longArr[1])/parseFloat(longDivStr);
```

again, this way works great everywhere, just not in firefox in the web server >_>

anyone have any ideas? im going crazy whit this @_@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out why its not working, for some reason in firefox instead of reading a dot (.) it reads a comma (,) from the web service (done in vb.net)

locally it reads it as a dot too, not online, so I suppose it has to do something with my IIS server O_o

hope this helps someone out there...

Answer (score 1):

I have never hear of such an error as The Flash run-time is supposed to make the different browsers and OS's interpret the SWF the same way.  I will say that I don't believe you should be using "new" in-front of your Number casting.

```
latStr:String = "28.7242100786401";
longStr:String = "-106.12635420984";

var cLat:Number = new Number(latStr);
var cLong:Number = new Number(longStr);
```

This should be:

```
var cLat:Number = Number(latStr); //Number is right because its a Floating Point, but remove new.
var cLong:Number = Number(longStr); //Number is right because its a Floating Point, but remove new.
```

I tested the using the following and saw no rounding take place.

var latStr:String = "28.7242100786401";
var longStr:String = "-106.12635420984";

```
trace(parseFloat(latStr)); //Outputs:  "28.7242100786401";
trace(parseFloat(longStr)); //Outputs:  "-106.12635420984";

trace(Number(latStr)); //Outputs:  "28.7242100786401";
trace(Number(longStr)); //Outputs:  "-106.12635420984";
```

I do not see why you require this workaround.  Also I use firefox as my main browser and your site seems to be working just fine.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.

it doesn't work in any computer I have tested it in, all with different types of flash player (9, 10, debugg and non debugg)

Comment: Can you please explain what I am looking for in the link to your page.  Perhaps a screen shot showing the error?  I see no such rounding as you have indicated.

Comment: using a sniffer, I see that the following fails
  - http://mundobuk.com/prueba/mapa/assets/ico/null
Is this what you mean?

Comment: hey, thanks for helping, look at this image   http://mundobuk.com/prueba/mapa/scrshot.jpg  
this is what I see on every computer

Comment: But using IE and Chrome everything works perfect, you see the correct value instead of NaN

Answer (score 1):

Comma is the separator for many European countries, so it's most likely the regional configuration on either the server or the client.